# Disk boot up from backup

Tags: debian, backup, disaster-recovery

I have a backup of my whole / partition except for /tmp /proc and /sys . Is there a way to boot this up into live? Backup is on 32 bit debian 5 OS

Thanks

Comment: You could always restore it.

Comment: Depending on your needs boot up a live image and chroot into it.  What are you trying to accomplish: modify something before restoring a backup, copy files off of the backup,...?